# Python: BeautifulSoup Pulling/Parsing data from within html tag

Tags: python, xml, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm attempting to pull sporting data from a url using Beautiful Soup in Python code. The issue I'm having with this data source is the data appears within the html tag. Specifically this tag is titled ""

I'm after the players data - which seems to be in XML format. However this data is appearing within the "match" tag rather that as the content within the start/end tag.

So like this:

```
print(soup.match)
```

Returns: (not going to include all the text):

```
<match :matchdata='{"match":{"id":"5dbb8e20-6f37-11eb-924a-1f6b8ad68.....ALL DATA HERE....>
</match>
```

Because of this when I try to output the contents as text it returns empty.

```
print(soup.match.text)
```

Returns: nothing

How would I extract this data from within the "" html tag. After this I would like to either save as an XML file or even better a CSV file would be ideal.

My python program from the beginning is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url="___MY_URL_HERE___"

# Make a GET request for html content
html_content = requests.get(url).text

# Parse the html content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")

## type(soup)
## <class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>

print(soup.match)
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you include the url along with the expected output in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tag may have any number of attributes. The tag  has an attribute “id” whose value is “boldest”. You can access a tag’s attributes by treating the tag like a dictionary
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes

So in your case

```
print(soup.match[":matchdata"])
```